# MySQL strangeness with dates and BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, date, between

I'm running a query to get rows that fall between certain dates (the current date and 7 days ago for this example).

I tried writing it as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM faulttracker.ft_v_cases 
WHERE DATE(cs_created) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
ORDER BY cs_created DESC;
```

but it returned 0 rows.  I couldn't understand why it didn't work, and I tried rewriting it as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM faulttracker.ft_v_cases 
WHERE DATE(cs_created) <= DATE(NOW()) 
AND DATE(cs_created) >= DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
ORDER BY cs_created DESC;
```

which DID work.

Why did the first one return 0 rows but the second one work as expected?  As far as I can see they should be functionally equivalent.

cs_created is a datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between), BETWEEN expects the following format:

```
 expr BETWEEN min AND max
```

In your first example, you are putting the min value last.

Try using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM faulttracker.ft_v_cases 
WHERE DATE(cs_created) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE(NOW()) 
ORDER BY cs_created DESC;
```

Comment: You're right!  Guess I was having a brain fade this morning and totally missed that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can just as well use:

```
WHERE cs_created >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
  AND cs_created <  CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This should return same results, but also allow the query to use index on `cs_created`.

Comment: Why do you think the other formulations do not allow the use of an index?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: because other solutions use a function on the `cs_created` column. MySQL does not use an index in case like that (since it needs to calculate the result of a function)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the index usage. And you could also use the constant CURRENT_DATE instead of the function CURDATE(). CURRENT_DATE works in many other dbms's as well, it's a SQL Standard.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition should be -

```
WHERE DATE(cs_created) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE(NOW())
```

The lower date value should be on left side when using Between.

Answer (score 0):

You must always have the range working as `BETWEEN smaller AND larger`; the treatment is the same regardless of whether you write:

```
x BETWEEN smaller AND larger
x >= smaller AND x <= larger
```

Hence, your code using BETWEEN needs to be written as:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM faulttracker.ft_v_cases 
 WHERE DATE(cs_created) BETWEEN DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE(NOW())
 ORDER BY cs_created DESC;
```

That covers the last 8 days, of course, since the range with BETWEEN/AND is inclusive.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried putting it like this:

`SELECT * 
FROM faulttracker.ft_v_cases 
WHERE CAST(cs_created AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(NOW() AS DATE) AND CAST(DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS DATE) 
ORDER BY cs_created DESC;`

the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html) states:

> to achieve best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type.

Comment: Using CAST on values that are already DATE values seems overkill, and that is not the source of the trouble.